# Getting the value of a paper-radio-button inside a template

Tags: javascript, polymer, material-design

I have set up a template that pulls the headers from some data from a JSON file then creates a set of paper-radio-buttons from those headers. When I call this template (in a paper-shadow) I am having trouble capturing the value of the selected paper-radio-button when I click submit (in the paper-shadow).

Here's what is generated in the paper-shadow:

```
<polymer-element name="add-graphItem">
    <template>
        <div id="div" layout horizontal>
            <paper-button raised class="colored" self-center>Upload File</paper-button>
            <paper-input-decorator label="Enter URL for Dataset" floatingLabel error="A URL is required!" flex self-center>
                <input is="core-input" id="graphSource" required>
            </paper-input-decorator>
        </div>
        <div layout horizontal center-justified id="upload-options"> 
            <paper-shadow class="card upload-options-box" z="1">
                <core-header-panel flex id="graphHeaderList">
                    <core-toolbar class="upload-option-header">
                      <span flex>Variable</span>
                    </core-toolbar>
                    <graph-optionsLoadTest><graph-optionsLoadTest> <!-- this is where I call the paper-radio-button -->

            </core-header-panel>
        </paper-shadow>
        <paper-shadow class="card upload-options-box" z="1">
            <core-header-panel flex>
                <core-toolbar class="upload-option-header top">
                  <span flex>Transform</span>
                </core-toolbar>
                <div class="upload-options">
                    <graph-functionsLoad><graph-functionsLoad> <!-- I also do another set here but I'm just working on the one for now since they do the same thing -->
                </div>
            </core-header-panel>
        </paper-shadow>
    </div>

    <paper-button dismissive hover on-tap="{{cancelGraph}}">Cancel</paper-button>
    <paper-button affirmative hover on-tap="{{addNewGraph}}">Submit</paper-button>

</template>
<script>
    Polymer("add-graphItem",{
        addNewGraph: function () {

            console.log(this.$.headerValue.selectedItem);
            var hValue = this.$.headerValue.selectedItem;
            console.log(hValue);
        },

        cancelGraph: function () {
            this.$.addGraph.toggle();
        },
    })
</script>
```

And here is the paper-radio-button template:

```
<link rel="import" href="/static/bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">

<polymer-element name="graph-optionsLoadTest">
    <template>
        <core-ajax auto url="/getDataHeaders"
               handleAs="json" response="{{headerList}}"></core-ajax>

        <paper-radio-group id="headerValue">
            <template repeat="{{h in headerList.headers}}">
                <paper-radio-button name='{{h}}' label='{{h}}'></paper-radio-button>
            </template>
        </paper-radio-group>

    </template>

    <script>

        Polymer( "graph-optionsLoadTest", {
            headerListChanged: function(oldValue) {
                console.log(this.headerList);

                // this.headers;
            }

        });


    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I've tried numerous ways to get the value of the selected paper-radio-group with no success, any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mike, I see a few issues that might help you.

First, you can only use the `$` hash to access nodes defined with an `id` attribute in your template. To access other nodes, such as those defined dynamically or without an `id` attribute, you can use the `querySelector` method. This method also lets you search by selector (somewhat like JQuery). In addition, to access nodes within the shadow DOM of a Polymer component that do **not** have `id` attributes, you may use the `shadowRoot` member. These ideas are discussed in the Polymer documentation for [Automatic Node Finding](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/polymer.html#automatic-node-finding) and, in more detail, in the section on [Shadow DOM](https://www.polymer-project.org/platform/shadow-dom.html). (In addition, the closing tag for the `<graph-optionsLoadTest>` element is missing a `/`.)

The upshot is that in order to access a node within a nested component's shadow DOM, you need to use something either like

- `this.$.idOfgraphOptionsLoadTest.$.idOfRadioGroup`, when you have defined `id` attributes for your elements;
- `this.shadowRoot.querySelector('graphOptionsLoadTest').shadowRoot.querySelector('paper-radio-group')`, whether or not `id` attributes are defined; or
- some combination of the two, when one component has `id`s and the other does not.

I would suggest giving the `<graph-optionsLoadTest>` element an `id` and using the first option above.

### Example Code

Unfortunately, your code is rather difficult to use without the pieces that I surmise are hosting it. Therefore, I created the following to illustrate the principle:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=yes">
        <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-radio-button/paper-radio-button.html">
        <link rel="import" href="bower_components/paper-radio-group/paper-radio-group.html">
    </head>
    <body unresolved fullbleed>
        <polymer-element name="options-load" attributes="selected">
            <template>
                <paper-radio-group id="headerValue" selected="{{selected}}">
                    <template repeat="{{h in headerList.headers}}">
                        <paper-radio-button name='{{h}}' label='{{h}}' style="height: 100px"></paper-radio-button>
                    </template>
                </paper-radio-group>
            </template>
            <script>
                Polymer({
                    created: function() {
                        this.selected = 0;
                        this.headerList = {
                            headers: ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option C']
                        };
                    }
                });
            </script>
        </polymer-element>

        <polymer-element name="add-graph-item">
            <template>
                <div layout horizontal around-justified>
                    <div>Options:</div>
                    <options-load id="optionsLoad"></options-load>
                    <button on-tap="{{doIt}}">Go</button>
                    <div>Results:&nbsp;</div>
                    <div id="results"></div>
                </template>
                <script>
                    Polymer({
                        doIt: function(event, detail, sender) {
                            var radioVal = this.$.optionsLoad.$.headerValue.selectedItem;
                            var msgTxt = 'Go clicked; ' + radioVal.label + ' selected'
                            console.log(msgTxt);
                            this.$.results.innerText = msgTxt;
                        }
                    });
                </script>
            </polymer-element>

            <add-graph-item></add-graph-item>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Good luck!

Comment: Hey Joppe - this was perfect! Really helped me understand a bit more about how to work around in the shadow DOM too - I really struggle sometimes getting down to the right granularity and though that `this.$.headerValue.selectedItem` would get me there (also thanks for picking up the missing `/` in my template call

Comment: Also if anyone wants it I created a plunker with Joppe's code working in it http://plnkr.co/edit/CrS9n9iZ8pusqJcYijrz?p=preview